# Integral contour deformation of the entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I have an integral

$$\int_\gamma e^{-z + z^3/3} dz,$$

where $\gamma$ is a contour in a complex plane going from infinity back to infinity (in some other direction). How can I figure out which contour deformations are allowed and which not?

Since both polynomials and the exponential function are entire functions it follows $e^{-z + z^3/3}$ is also entire. But somehow it seems I still can not change the contour of integration completely arbitrarily?

Comment: You need to be pretty careful here: The integrand has an essential singularity at infinity. and the integral is probably not going to converge in any meaningful sense (depending on the choice of contour).

Comment: Tnx! How do I proceed if I want to investigate these different contours, i.e., if I want to know for which contours integral is meaningful (if it converges)?